# pick first date in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a column of dates: -

```
dates
2021-06-24 05:47:05
2021-06-24 09:47:05
2021-06-24 13:47:05
2021-06-24 17:47:05
```

i want to pick first time of the day that is 3 hours or more than 3 hours apart from next time of the day. date is always same.

expected output:-

```
2021-06-24 05:47:05
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LEAD we can get "the value from the next row", then reduce the result set to only those dates where the next date is greater than 3h away from this date. Finally just pick the min one of those

```
select min(dates)
from (
  select dates, lead(dates) over (order by dates) as next_date
  from yourtable
) x
where next_date >= x.dates + interval '3 hour'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(date) over (order by date) as lead_date
      from t
     ) t
where t <= lead_date + interval '3 hour'
order by t.date
limit 1;
```

Comment: this doesn't work if first date itself is 3 hours apart from next date, can u plz update the answer, I have updated my question

Comment: @a_dog_with_no_master . . . It answered the question that you asked.  It is somewhat rude to change questions to invalidate answers.  But the change for the query is really pretty minor, just using `lead()` instead of `lag()` and changing the comparisons.